# multiple USERNAME_FIELD in djangorestframework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

How can i allow users to authenticate via multiple username field e.g(email | phone_number as USERNAME_FIELD)??

I have a custom User model---> in which I have a USERNAME_FIELD set to 'email'.

settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', 
     #THis is a default Backend which points to CustomUser's USERNAME_FIELD. 

    'account.backends.AuthenticateBackend', 
    ##Custom Backend which tells to use phone number as USERNAME_FIELD.
]
```

Here's the issue!
It works fine if I use default obtain_auth_token view e.g.(allows me to login via multiple field)---> but whenever I write my own login logic it skips default model backend settings thus, it greets me with error.

```
ValueError: Field 'phone_number' expected a number but got 'someEmail@gmail.com'.
```

Comment: Why not write a custom backend for authentication?

Comment: @ilyasbbu Not to worry I fixed it. added a extra argument in custom authentication method.

Comment: @ilyasbbu I have a custom authentication method if you look at my AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS the second one is custom one. The problem is whenever I try to authenticate user it only uses custom authentication method which has a phone_number as a username, it skips the default method. That's why its gives a error whenever I try to login in via email address.